# How to post value from one php page to another using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post one value which I got using Jquery, so I have to pass that value to php page using ajax. but when I did this I got Undefined index data error.

Here is my code:

```
$("#requirementtable tbody tr").on("click", function(){
                        desc =  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4)").text().trim();
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"get_diagnosis.php",
        data: desc,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {      
            alert("some error occured->" + jqXHR.responseJSON);
        }
    })
  })
```

this is my php code:

```
<?php 
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `desc` variable has some value in it and you have to `post` data like,

```
data: {data:desc},
```

AJAX Code,

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"get_diagnosis.php",
    data: {data:desc},
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {      
        alert("some error occured->" + jqXHR.responseJSON);
    }
});
```

And in PHP use `isset()` to prevent undefined errors like,

```
<?php 
    $data = isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : 'Not defined';
    echo $data;
?>
```

If you want `JSON` response format then use `dataType:'json'` in `$.ajax`, and use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) in PHP to respond it.

Answer (score 3):

here is a simple example that contains your code and solution

```
//Data Object        
var obj={
           name:"uneeb",
           city:"gujranwala",
           state: "punjab"
        };  
//Data Object   

//Ajax Request to Server
     $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'someFile.php',
          data:object,
          success: function (data) {
                  //do something here
              }
          });
//Ajax Request to Server

//PHP

echo $_POST['name']; //prints uneeb
echo $_POST['city']; //prints gujranwala
echo $_POST['state']; //prints punjab

//PHP
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the followings:

```
desc =  $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(4)").text().trim();
//        remove ^^^^^^^^^^ since you're currently in tr click
desc =  $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").text().trim();
```

And replace to:

```
data: desc,
```

With:

```
data: {data:desc}, //to pass data as object as you don't have serialized data
```

And inside your php code, you can get data using `$_POST['data']`.

Answer (score 1):

replace this `data: desc,` field in your ajax to `data:{data: desc},`, this is the cause you are not getting data in your php code